# How to keep dynamically added row in a scroll-able table

Tags: javascript, css

```js
function addField (argument) {
    var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
    var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
    var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

    var linksBox = document.createElement("text");
    linksBox.setAttribute("name", "links" + currentIndex);

    var keywordsBox = document.createElement("input");
    keywordsBox.setAttribute("name", "keywords" + currentIndex);

    var violationsBox = document.createElement("input");
    violationsBox.setAttribute("name", "violationtype" + currentIndex);



    var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(linksBox);

    currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(keywordsBox);

    currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
    currentCell.appendChild(violationsBox);

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" style="height:50px; overflow:auto;">
    <tr>
        <td name="links">Upgrade</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="keywords"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="violationtype"></td>
        <td><input type="button" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField();"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I'm dynamically adding the rows to table. Where table height is '50px or 100px'. Added style 'overflow:auto'.

When i keep adding the rows, rows are keeping added and ignoring the height of table, mentioned above.

Please help me to fix the height of table, which will be scroll-able.

Using the above code in Django.

Comment: have you tired max-height: 50px ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `display:block` on your table to make it scrollable :

```js
function addField(argument) {
  var myTable = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
  var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

  var linksBox = document.createElement("text");
  linksBox.setAttribute("name", "links" + currentIndex);

  var keywordsBox = document.createElement("input");
  keywordsBox.setAttribute("name", "keywords" + currentIndex);

  var violationsBox = document.createElement("input");
  violationsBox.setAttribute("name", "violationtype" + currentIndex);



  var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(linksBox);

  currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(keywordsBox);

  currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
  currentCell.appendChild(violationsBox);

}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" style="height:50px; overflow:auto; display:block;">
  <tr>
    <td name="links">Upgrade</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="keywords"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="violationtype"></td>
    <td><input type="button" class="button" value="Add another line" onclick="addField();"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```